# antlr4 - parsing f1vae

Tags: antlr, antlr4

```
grammar Expr;

// parser rules
prog : ((decl_list expr | expr) ';' NEWLINE?)*;

decl_list : decl decl_list
     | decl
     ;

decl : DEF fun var_list '=' expr ENDEF
     | DEF fun '=' expr ENDEF
     ;

var_list : param var_list 
     | param 
     ;

expr : LET var '=' expr IN              # assignExpr
     | fun '()'                         # callExpr
     | fun '(' expr_list ')'            # callExpr
     | expr ('*'|'/') expr              # infixExpr
     | expr ('+'|'-') expr              # infixExpr 
     | '(' expr ')'                     # parensExpr
     | num                              # numberExpr
     | '~' expr                         # negateExpr
     | var                              # varExpr
     ;

expr_list : expr',' expr_list
     | expr
     ;

num  : '-'? INT
     | '-'? FLOAT
     ;

var  : STR ('_' | '-') var
     | STR
     ;

fun  : STR ('0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9') fun
     | STR
     ;

param : STR '_' param
     | STR
     ;

// lexer rules                    
NEWLINE: [\r\n]+ ;
INT: [0-9]+ ;          // should handle negatives
FLOAT: [0-9]+'.'[0-9]* ; // should handle signs(+/-)
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
DEF: 'def';
ENDEF: 'endef';
LET: 'let';
IN: 'in';
STR: [a-zA-Z]+;
```

I am trying to make f1vae intepreter with antlr4.
the parser starts with prog.
the problem occurs with the decl_list part when i put this:

```
def f = 3 endef def g x y = x + y endef let x = f() in g(1,x);
line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'deff=3'
line 1:6 mismatched input '=' expecting {';', '*', '/', '+', '-'}
```

why is the lexer thinking def f = 3 as "deff=3", not as decl?
it doesn't catch DEF = 'def' in lexer rules.
what is the problem? there seems to be no overlapping lexer rules.

Comment: You don't say how you run the parser. Is this in Java, or through an IDE with Antlr extension, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see "deff=3" is that you've skipped spaces, so the parser does not see them.  (This is not "wrong"; it's quite common to do, but it explains the error message).

The Lexer is handling that input just fine. Here are the first few tokens:

```
[@0,0:2='def',<'def'>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='f',<STR>,1:4]
[@2,6:6='=',<'='>,1:6]
[@3,8:8='3',<'3'>,1:8]
[@4,10:14='endef',<'endef'>,1:10]
```

It's the parse that doesn't have a viable alternative.

This token stream does seem like it should match the `DEF fun '=' expr ENDEF` alternative of your `decl` rule, but I get the same error message.

To simplify you `fun` rule just a bit I added a `DIGIT: [0-9];` lexer rule and changed the `fun` rule to:

```
fun: STR DIGIT fun | STR;
```

(It also works with `DIGIT` defined as `DIGIT: ('0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9');` so, expanding it out is not the problem.)

With that change (and adding a `;` after "f() in" in your input), I get a successful parse.

Admittedly, it's not immediately obvious to me why that doesn't work with the digit characters as inline alternatives in the parser rule, but it's probably more straightforward as a LExer rule anyway.

As an aside, you can change your `fun` rule to a non-recursive version that accepts the same input and will result in a simpler parse tree:

```
fun: STR (DIGIT STR)*;
```

(similar could be done for your `var` rule)

Comment: BTW, from looking at your previous question, I suspect that your refactoring of `var`, `fun`, and `param` are not achieving what you want (at least, they don't match the same input as your rules on the previous question)